# How do I return a specific data from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want my output to be **Delhi** when I put **India** as input for the following data

```
{
  data: [{
      country: 'India',
      capital: 'Delhi'
    },
    {
      country: 'Pakisthan',
      capital: 'Islamabad'
    },
    {
      country: 'China',
      capital: 'Beijing'
    },
    {
      country: 'Bhutan',
      capital: 'Thimphu'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Clearly you should implement a `countryToCapital` function. What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Array.prototype.find method:

```js
var obj = {
  data: [{
    country: 'India',
    capital: 'Delhi'
  }, {
    country: 'Pakisthan',
    capital: 'Islamabad'
  }, {
    country: 'China',
    capital: 'Beijing'
  }, {
    country: 'Bhutan',
    capital: 'Thimphu'
  }]
}

function getCapital(country, arr) {
  return (arr.find(function(el) {
    return el.country == country;
  }) || {}).capital;
}

console.log(getCapital("India", obj.data)); // Delhi
```